# Invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'NSString')

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, int

I'm trying to make an Age counter, but there is an error in the first line:

> "Invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'NSString')"

```
-(IBAction)OK:(id)sender; {   
    Age = 2013 - textfield.text ;   
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i" , Age];
```

Comment: BTW, standard coding convention is to have variable and method names begin with a lower-case character -- use names starting with Upper Case for class names. Your code is much easier for others to understand if you follow this convention.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the integer value of the text and then you can do subtraction using it.  But the NSString's intValue may return 0 if the string is not convertable to an int (ex. "this" is not an int...).

```
-(IBAction)OK:(id)sender; {   
    Age = 2013 - [textfield.text intValue] ;   
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i" , Age];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a small mistake here. You are subtracting string value from integer in this:

```
Age = 2013 - textfield.text ;
```

Use this instead of above line:

```
int Age = 2013 - [textfield.text intValue] ;
```